# jQuery - add a class and remove it after 500ms

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a class and remove it after 500 miliseconds. It does not work with delay(). To give an simple example I do it here with a background-color:

[code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gnaer)

jQuery

```
$('.box').click(function(){

 $('.box').addClass("bg1").delay(500).removeClass("bg1");
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a `timeout` for this.

In your case: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j6y4/1/)

```
$('.box').on('click', function(){

    var self = $(this);

    self.addClass("bg1");

    setTimeout(function(){
        self.removeClass("bg1");
    }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a timeout or if using delay, you need to put it in queue:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/punbv)

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    $('.box').addClass("bg1").dequeue().delay(500).queue(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("bg1");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Timeout Function in jquery will give u the better result..

i.e

```
$('.box').click(function(){
        $('.box').addClass("bg1");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.box').removeClass("bg1");
        },500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Do stuff
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box').click(function(){
 $('.box').addClass("bg1");
 setTimeout(function() {
    $('.box').removeClass("bg1")
 }, 500);
});
```

it could be done like that

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    $('.box').addClass("bg1");
    setTimeout("$('.box').removeClass('bg1')", 500);
});
```

Comment: -1: Dont pass strings to `setTimeout`!

Comment: Why not ?           .............

Comment: Because [eval == evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx) (And passing a string to `setTimeout` is just eval in disguise!)

Comment: Fair comment . . . Ok, create a function with the removeClass code and call it from the setTimeout . . . Happy ? ;o)

Comment: ...or just remove the quotes, and wrap what you've got in `function(){ ... }`. As per the 5 other answers ;)